# Can i mention multiple TAG before class in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I simply want to know can I mention multiple tags before class to short my code. I've made the table and want to make border for `<th>,<td>,<table>` only by mentioning it before class.

Now:

```
table.maintable{    
    opacity: 87%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.maintable{
    opacity: 87%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.maintable{
    opacity: 87%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Do something like this:

```
table.th.td.maintable{    
    opacity: 87%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Can I do it via class without using id?

Comment: just use `.maintable { opacity: 87%; border: 2px solid black; }` it will apply to everthing that uses the class. No matter what it is, table, th or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution :

```
table.maintable,
th.maintable,
td.maintable {
    opacity: 87%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```